# Getting 'integer out of range' error sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, blaze, odo

So, I am using `odo` for data migration but came across this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) integer out of range
```

Both the source and the destination tables have the same schema but in the sql statement being executed in the backend the integer values have .0 with them. Like the integer `34` in the source table is shown as `34.0`:

```
[SQL: INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2,col3) VALUES (%(col1)s, %(col2)s, %(col3)s] 
[parameters: ({'col2' : val2', 'col3' : val3', 'col1' : val1})]
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: This might be because of `NaN` value for an integer column in the parameter dictionary. Added a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074487/copy-empty-string-to-integer-column-postgres

Answer (score 0):

The sql string should be:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (
    %(col1)s::numeric::int, 
    %(col2)s::numeric::int, 
    %(col3)s::numeric::int
)
```

If the target column is not nullable and the source value can be `None` then coalesce it:

```
    coalesce(%(col1)s::numeric::int, 0),
```

Comment: The sql string is what odo is showing as output when the error is occurring. I can't change it.

Comment: As I cannot change the sql string, how can I go about this?